# Database for Mobile applications

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase

I would like build a mobile application in order to learn the technology.

I have chosen Ionic framework for the same, as it takes care of majority of settings for building the application. But, when coming to database for the app which I am trying to build, I am bit confused.

Some links as a result of googling suggest me to use SQLite and some pull me towards Firebase. My doubt is, are they related for comparison? I guess, SQLite and Firebase cannot be compared with. Please clarify.

Thanks
Manikandan J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite is your phone's database and Firebase is an online database.

Using SQLite, you can create apps which do not support sharing with others. An example, pac man. Say you got a highscore of "20". But you cannot share this highscore with other people's phones because it is local (inside your phone).

Using Firebase, you can store data online, for example, registration details etc. Once people have registered they can login with their info using multiple platforms (depending on your target). You can make them share things with eachother and so on.

Comment: but firebase is offline too

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is more suitable fro developing offline android application. Firebase always required a server but SQLite did'nt require any server so for Firebase you should have internet required but in SQLite you can achieve your goal offline. So depending upon the conditions you can use one of this.

Comment: Sorry, it's wrong, firebase can be used offline and it sync data when the device is online.